# Java Application can't write to disk though full permissions are given

Tags: java, windows, permissions, filesystems, user-permissions

I am trying to write to C:\{foldername}\batches\{date}\batch.csv from a Java application. Admin accounts are able to write to the folder, but those without an admin account cannot. The non-admin users have full permissions to write to that folder, creating directories and files as well as updating, and they can do so using Explorer but not the application. I also have a SQL file that outputs to a similar directory that works just fine under a standard user ever since those users got write permission to that folder. I assume it is a permissions issue, but they have full permission on the folder. Insight?

Comment: Has another process locked the file? There are free programs that will tell you which process is locking while file(s) for Windows

Comment: If you have any exceptions please share, other than that we can only speculate.#

Comment: I have it throwing exceptions into a popup window for the time being and I am getting nothing.

Comment: Another process has not locked the file. They are only getting created by this application and we are not doing anything with them after they are created.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the File is writable using the following-

```
File f = new File("path");
if(f.canWrite()) {
  // write access
} else {
  // no write access
}
```

Try to exclusively make the file writable using the following if it is a permission issue-

```
file.setWritable(false);
```